# Xcode, SFML error dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml, dyld

I am trying to start a basic C++ project with link to SFML library.
I have unzipped the SFML library to folder /Users/mulperi/cpplib/sfml 
and I have added that to *Include Search Path* and *Library Search Path*.

My code is simple, I followed a tutorial on Youtube (also tried different ready-made codes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "First SML Window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The build succeeds so the paths should be fine. I don't get the window, instead I have these outputs:

**Thread 1:**

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x10003b1e0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x10003b1e5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10003b1e8 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10003b1ea <+10>: jae    0x10003b1f4               ; <+20>
    0x10003b1ec <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10003b1ef <+15>: jmp    0x10003aa48               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x10003b1f4 <+20>: retq   
    0x10003b1f5 <+21>: nop    
    0x10003b1f6 <+22>: nop    
    0x10003b1f7 <+23>: nop
```

**Output:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-system.2.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mulperi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfml_1-cgodahbmxiufqnhhglbsyfuzvdvz/Build/Products/Debug/sfml_1
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

I am using Xcode 9.3.1 on High Sierra 10.13.4

**Update:**
I also tried moving the SFML folder inside the project folder and even tried splitting up include,libs,frameworks,extlibs tu /usr/local like in the SFML tutorial but I always get the same output.

Here are pics of my settings
[image: Folder structure]

[image: Header search path]

[image: Library search path]

[image: Added frameworks too]

[image: The output]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I got it working after reading the getting started tutorial carefully again. On Mac, they recommend using the Framework files, so what I did was:

1. Copy contents of SFML/Frameworks and SFML/extlibs to /Library/Frameworks
2. Xcode project Build phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> Add every SFML framework from the /Library/Frameworks folder (no need to add the extlib frameworks)

Note: No need to add Include Search Paths or Library Search Paths with this method.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: Still not working here macOS 10.15.4, Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a). Xcode is complaining about the signature of the files on framework and stops the compilation process

Comment: @EduardoPereira You need to go to Mac's System Preferences, Security, and from there individually Admit permission for each framework one by one.

Comment: In my case, on top of the other things mentioned, I had to go Signing & Capabilities-> Hardened Runtime-> check Disable Library Validation

Answer (score 1):

On Catalina the accepted solution does not seem to work anymore due to errors like:

> sfml-audio.framework cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Using homebrew solved it for me:

- `brew install sfml`. Then on Xcode link the libraries installed by homebre by:
- Navigating to the section 'Link Binaries With Libraries' on Xcode, drag and drop the sfml libraries from `/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/x.x.x/lib` directory
- Click build and run. Project should now build and run successfully

Comment: I did the exactly the same, but have had source problem yet..

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the next steps in **MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 (in 2020)**:

**for use SFML in Xcode, try this:**

--> **1. Install sfml dependency with: $ brew install sfml**

--> **2. Go to Xcode project and add the following:(Very Important)**

in "Header Search Paths" add "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/include"

in "Library Search aths" add "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1/lib

2.5.1 is the sfml **version**, try with your current version.

--> **3. Go to "Build Phases / Link Binary with Libraries" section and add all "dylib" files:**

- '''-network.'''.dylib.
- '''-window.'''.dylib.
- '''-audio.'''.dylib.
- '''-system.'''.dylib.
- '''-graphics.'''.dylib.

--> **4. Finally, run your project.**

Verify that all includes have been correctly added at top of file program and the namespace is correctly placed like:

`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`

`#include <iostream>`

`using namespace sf;`

Comment: I did the same steps, but have the source problem.. Program compiled and linked, but have SIGABRT and output "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-system.2.5.dylib"

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on MacOS Ventura 13.6 (2023):

1. After following the previous steps, installing sfml with homebrew | adding the paths to the **Header/Library Search Paths** | adding ".dylib" files to **Build Phases / Link Binary with Libraries**
2. Under **Build Settings/Signing** set the option **Enable Hardened Runtime: No**
3. Click build and run.

If the problem persists try changing other values under the **Build Settings / Signing** list

[Apple | Hardened Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime#)